# Generics and Rx

Tags: c#, generics, system.reactive

I am trying to convert this program to use generics. However, on the line

```
foreach (var observer in observerList)
{                           
   observer.OnNext(observer);
}
```

I get:

```
Cannot convert from System.IObserver<T> to T
```

Program:

```
public sealed class EnumerableObservable<T> : IObservable<T>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> enumerable;

    public EnumerableObservable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        this.enumerable = enumerable;
        this.cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.cancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token;

        this.workerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
                foreach (var value in this.enumerable)
                {
                    //if task cancellation triggers, raise the proper exception
                    //to stop task execution

                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    foreach (var observer in observerList)
                    {                           
                        observer.OnNext(observer);
                    }
                }
            }, this.cancellationToken);
    }

    //the cancellation token source for starting stopping
    //inner observable working thread
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource;

    //the cancellation flag
    private readonly CancellationToken cancellationToken;

    //the running task that runs the inner running thread
    private readonly Task workerTask;

    //the observer list
    private readonly List<IObserver<T>> observerList = new List<IObserver<T>>();

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        observerList.Add(observer);
        //subscription lifecycle missing
        //for readability purpose

        return null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //trigger task cancellation
        //and wait for acknoledge

        if (!cancellationSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            cancellationSource.Cancel();
            while (!workerTask.IsCanceled)
                Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        cancellationSource.Dispose();
        workerTask.Dispose();

        foreach (var observer in observerList)
            observer.OnCompleted();
    }
}

public sealed class ConsoleStringObserver<T> : IObserver<T>
{
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-> END");
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-> {0}", error.Message);
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-> {0}", value.ToString());
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //we create a variable containing the enumerable
        //this does not trigger item retrieval
        //so the enumerator does not begin flowing datas

        var enumerable = EnumerateValuesFromSomewhere();
        using (var observable = new EnumerableObservable<string>(enumerable))
        using (var observer = observable.Subscribe(new ConsoleStringObserver<string>()))
        {
            //wait for 2 seconds than exit
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN to EXIT");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateValuesFromSomewhere()
    {
        var random = new Random(DateTime.Now.GetHashCode());

        while (true) //forever
        {
            //returns a random integer number as string
            yield return random.Next().ToString();

            //some throttling time
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should say `observer.OnNext(value);`

Comment: LOL. Typo.Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a field called observerList. This is a list of IObserver.

```
private readonly List<IObserver<T>> observerList = new List<IObserver<T>>();
```

You are passing all the elements on this loop and trying to pass with parameter himself.

```
foreach (var observer in observerList)
{                           
    observer.OnNext(observer);
}
```

`observer.OnNext` it expected T and not himself.

For example, if is `IObserver<string>` you need to pass a string

```
observer.OnNext("Hello world");
```

I can't understand your program, but if you show me can help you.